# Displaying NDVI from MYD09Q1 product with TIMESAT

Tags: timesat

I use MODIS surface reflectance (MYD09Q1) for calculate NDVI in GEE and save it to .dat(ENVI std. format) then use TIMESAT image view to display the mosaic data, encountering file size warning:
Hi I received this error: file size does not match no or rows * no or columns * no of bytes. will still attempt to drow.

[image: file size warning ti time sat]

Comment: Please include your full error message using formatted text rather than only as a picture.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Comment: Using File info in Timesat you will get the no. of rows and columns for your raster. and then input the correct no. of rows and columns your  image will display